# How to get the computer name using the IP Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dns, ip-address, computer-name

I am trying to get the computer name for the current user.  I am able to get the IP address using `System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("ComputerName").Address.ToString()` but when I replace the *ComputerName*with the *IPAddress* I receive the following error.

**No such host is known**

I enabled reverse DNS in IIS7 by running command: 
**Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set w3svc/EnableReverseDNS TRUE**
in the  **C:\inetpub\AdminScripts** directory on my server.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

### Update

The overall purpose is that this will be a help desk application and it will be useful for a user to be able to easily provide their computer name for assistance.

Locally everything works but it does not work once published to the server.

Comment: That code runs locally.  It won't tell you the IP of the remote user; it will tell you the IP of a computer on the local area network.

Comment: Have you tried Dns.GetHostByName? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname(v=vs.100).aspx... From that document, "The GetHostByName method queries the Internet DNS server for host information. If you pass an empty string as the host name, this method retrieves the standard host name for the local computer." so it seems as though if you pass it a name it will look it up accordingly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey For now, I am hard coding the IP address and host/computer name of a client into `Dns.GetHostEntry(hostNameOrAddress)` to see if I can get the desired result.  The name works fine but the IP gives an error.

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit OS? If you get the IP address from a 64bit machine you need to cycle through and get the IPv4 address. The first returned address is probably IPv6.

Comment: @alykins The goal is get the host/computer name by using the IP Address. GetHostByName requires the host name to already be known.

Comment: @StackingOverflows I put both solutions in my answer. I don't know what you want to do with it after that, but it's tested and displays remote machine IP, and then remote machine name via IP

Comment: @StackingOverflows... Have you tried my solution? I've used the Dns. class a lot. I also tested that just for you on a remote machine. You just need to take it and plug it in where you need it.

Comment: @alykins The code you posted gets the correct IP when supplied the machine name but fails on `string name = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName.ToString();`

Comment: @StackingOverflows check comment I posted in answer. Are you trying to pass it an IP as a string eg "123.123.123.123" or are you trying to pass it as an IPAddress? It needs the IPAddress (not string) or it will try to look for a machine named "123.123.123.123" which probably won't be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to obtain it on a different machine. This will also give you the IPv4 version.

```
class getIP
{
    public getIP()
    {

        IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("whybla01").AddressList.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
        Console.WriteLine(ip);
        string name = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: just be sure to pass it an IPAddress

Comment: I substituted the `"whybla01"` with the computer name and the IP but received the same error.  I am starting to think that it is an issue that needs to be resolved on the server.  Thanks again.

Comment: @StackingOverflows did you pass it an IP in string form ("123.123.123.123"- You need to parse it to a real IPAddress), or as an IPAddress? But yes if this is not working for you then most likely there is something configured wrong on the server.

Comment: @StackingOverflows you can actually make that real quick by making a console app and then adding that class in (that's how I tested it for you). If you do that you can throw break points on it real quick/easily. Try doing that and throwing a break point on Console.WriteLine(ip); What is the value? Or does it throw an error before that line?

Comment: @StackingOverflows the GetHostEntry() accepts string (of machine), or IPAddress (parsed and not a string). It's really for setting IPHostEntry object but you can use it to pick off the host name or IP like I did in the example instead of creting a whole IPHostEntry object.

Some refs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
  string machineName = GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(yourIPAdress);

  private static string GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(string ipAdress)
        {
            string machineName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAdress);

                machineName = hostEntry.HostName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Machine not found...
            }
            return machineName;
        }
```

Comment: This get's the Dns entry for the machine the code is running on. This would work if you passed the target machine's IP.

Comment: @moez Thanks, but this is giving the same error: **No such host is known** on the Dns.GetHostEntry method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that answered this post.

Actually, the code was not the problem.   There was nothing wrong with the code that I was trying or the suggestions made.  I found out that the server DNS entry was not set up correctly.

Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: how view server DNS entry ?